# When does Django's Middleware framework hook the request?

Tags: django, django-middleware

Does the `Middleware` framework hook the request object before it is sent to the `urlconf`?
Also, does this hook happen after it goes through `WSGIHandler`?
So, just in respect to these three "layers", is it the order in which `request` is processed?
**WSGIHandler --> Middleware --> urlconf**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSGI handler is what coordinates all requests to your Python web application; technically, your WSGI handler is the code that calls the rest of the Django request/response process.  So everything is "going through" your WSGI handler, if you are using one.

When a request comes in, Django will construct a request object and successively pass it to each piece of registered middleware.  This request object is then passed to the view, which is expected to return a response object that may be serialized to a valid HTTP response.  Since the url conf simply maps a pattern to a view function, it doesn't matter when it is matched; ultimately, the corresponding view is called after the middleware.  So you may make assumptions in your view code that any registered middleware has already been executed.

Googling around produced [this high level view](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/06/django-request-response-processing/) of the process.